# Create new RelativeLayout above existing TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams, android-relativelayout

I have an issue with the creation of  a new `RelativeLayout` above an already existing `TextView` in my app.

My main layout is called `contentLayout` and inside it I have a `TextView` called `addRoomButton` :

```
RelativeLayout contentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentLayout);
TextView addRoomButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addRoomText);
```

I just want to add a new `RelativeLayout` **above** my `TextView` so I wrote this :

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
relativeLayout.setId(R.id.roomRelativeLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       100
);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, addRoomButton.getId());
contentLayout.addView(relativeLayout, rlp);
```

The `RelativeLayout` is well created on the top of my `contentLayout`, but my `TextView` is not visible. I think it's just behind `relativeLayout` but I'm not sure...

Is there any solutons to put the `TextView` below the new `RelativeLayout` without creating `LinearLayout` or other `Layouts`?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't  you do it by XML?

`layout_below=""`

Comment: Because the creation of the new layout is called by an OnClickListener, so the user can create any number of layouts he wants. 
**EDIT : ** the layout_above could only work if i put an id of the future layout, but it could have many new layouts.

Comment: hmm ok then it seems like your textview is hidden :(

Comment: I also tried a setVisibility() method to be sure, but nothing change, I think I have to insert differents layouts for new relativelayout and textview

Answer (score 0):

try out your idea with xml. put relativelayout with relativelayout(A) in it and button(B). set A to layout_above B and see there is no success. Set B bellow A and you get the effect you want. So you need to getLayoutParams() of your button and adjust it to be below your newly created layout.